# Get value from input property

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get value of data-cart-item-id from the input below. But I'm unable to do it.

```
<td>
<input
    id="qinput-xxx"
    data-link="http:xxxx"
    data-item-id="xxx"
    data-cart-item-id="xxxx"
    class="qty cart-item-quantity input-text" name=""
    value="1"
/>

<button id="qbutton-xxx"
        data-item-id="xxx"
        disabled="disabled"
        data-update
        data-cart-item-update
        class="button quantity-button">
    ok
</button>
</td>
```

I'm trying with the following code, but I'm getting nothing from it.

```
document.querySelectorAll('data-cart-item-id')
```

Comment: You mean you can't get the element from `querySelectorAll`? You need to put the data attribute name in brackets like: `document.querySelectorAll('[data-cart-item-id]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data-cart-item-id` is not a tag name. It is a property, so use `input[data-cart-item-id]` or `[data-cart-item-id]`.

Also `querySelectorAll` retuns an Array of elements, so you have to specify the index.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[data-cart-item-id]')[0].getAttribute('data-cart-item-id'));
```

```html
<td>
<input
    id="qinput-xxx"
    data-link="http:xxxx"
    data-item-id="xxx"
    data-cart-item-id="xxxx"
    class="qty cart-item-quantity input-text" name=""
    value="1"
/>

<button id="qbutton-xxx"
        data-item-id="xxx"
        disabled="disabled"
        data-update
        data-cart-item-update
        class="button quantity-button">
    ok
</button>
</td>
```

Comment: This is returning 1 and not "xxx" - the value of the property

Comment: changed to `getAttribute`. now try @FilipeFerminiano

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Since the `input` has it's own unique `id`, I would suggest you to use `getElementById` instead. Then, just get it's `data-cart-item-id` attribute value with `getAttribute` function.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('qinput-xxx'),
    data = elem.getAttribute('data-cart-item-id');
    console.log(data);
```

```html
<td>
  <input id="qinput-xxx" data-link="http:xxxx" data-item-id="xxx" data-cart-item-id="xxxx" class="qty cart-item-quantity input-text" name="" value="1" />
  <button id="qbutton-xxx" data-item-id="xxx" disabled="disabled" data-update data-cart-item-update class="button quantity-button">ok</button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get element by class name for example for
qty class if it is specified for products only then you will get array of products then use a for loop from 0 till element length then with in it use the getAttribute() function you will get that attribute value do your code with it.